# SQL Server 2008, restaurar .back sin management studio

Tags: sql-server

les explico un poco, tengo un aplicativo que instalo en las maquinas clientes junto con el sql express (sin management stdudio), el dilema es que tengo restaurar un backup, pero no se como hacerlo sin el management studio, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo? tal vez algún .exe que exista por ahí free o algo, todo sirve.

Comment: En este enlace encontre la respuesta: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190679(v=sql.120).aspx Como podran observar lo hace de otra manera aperturando la instancia y luego introduciendo los códigos. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes,

**Para hacer un backup:**

En el windows, entra como Administrador, ejecuta el CMD como administrador y dale el siguiente comando:

```
SqlCmd -E -S Server_Name –Q “BACKUP DATABASE [Name_of_Database] TO DISK=’X:PathToBackupLocation[Name_of_Database].bak'”
```

Estos ejemplos te podrían ser de utilidad:

Default SQL Server instance:

```
SqlCmd -E -S MyServer –Q “BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO DISK=’D:BackupsMyDB.bak'”
```

Named SQL Server instance:

```
SqlCmd -E -S MyServerMyInstance –Q “BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO DISK=’D:BackupsMyDB.bak'”
```

**Restaurar una base de datos desde linea de comandos:**

Para restaurar una base de datos desde un archivo de backup, utiliza el comando:

```
SqlCmd -E -S Server_Name –Q “RESTORE DATABASE [Name_of_Database] FROM DISK=’X:PathToBackupFile[File_Name].bak'”
```

Por ejemplo:

```
SqlCmd -E -S MyServer –Q “RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM DISK=’D:BackupsMyDB.bak'”
```

Referencia: http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/

Comment: No se en que me estoy equivocando pero me sale esto:

C:\Windows\system32>SqlCmd -E -S localhost\sqlexpress -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [xyz]
 TO DISK='D:xxx.bak'"
Sqlcmd: '-Q "RESTORE DATABASE [xyz] TO DISK='D:xxx.bak'"': argumento
inesperado. Escriba '-?' para obtener ayuda.

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Ya se, el to disk por el from

Comment: Da el mismo error: 

C:\Windows\system32>SqlCmd -E -S localhost\sqlexpress -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [xyz]
 FROM DISK='D:XXX.bak'"
Sqlcmd: '-Q "RESTORE DATABASE [xyz] FROM DISK='D:XXX.bak'"': argument
o inesperado. Escriba '-?' para obtener ayuda.

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: intenta con esto en el CMD como administrador:
SqlCmd -E -S SQLEXPRESS -Q "RESTORE DATABASE NombreDeMiBaseDeDatos FROM DISK='D:Archivo.bak'”, asegurate que no haya los corchetes [ ]

Comment: Da el mismo error de argumento inesperado

Comment: Estas copiando y pegando el código o estas tecleando, ojo con los signos "-" es diferente de "–"

Answer (score 1):

votar en contra
accept
En este enlace encontre la respuesta:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190679(v=sql.120).aspx

Como podrán observar lo hace de otra manera aperturando la instancia y luego introduciendo los códigos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor recomendación que te puedo dar para poder hacer esto es la ejecución de la restauración o respaldo de la base de datos desde el cmd a continuación te dejo un link el cual te redijera a una pagina con sintaxis y ejemplos de los solicitado:
http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/